# issue with headers to upload file through HTTP post (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, http-post, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm facing another problem with uploading file

I can't upload file to a php script and also can't read the output

I think uploader.upload() is fine and problem is just with header(web server is Apache)

my Uploader.upload() is drive me crazy :(

any idea what is wrong with code ?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, address):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)
        header.hide()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Add Upload', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleAddUpload)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.netaccess = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self._uploaders = {}

    def handleAddUpload(self):
        stream = QtCore.QFile('/home/me/icon.png')
        if stream.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            #data = stream.readAll()
            #stream.close()
            data = stream
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            button = QtGui.QPushButton('Abort', self.table)
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.handleAbort(row))
            progress = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.table)
            progress.setRange(0, data.size())
            self.table.setRowCount(row + 1)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, button)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 1, progress)
            uploader = self._uploaders[row] = Uploader(row, self.netaccess)
            uploader.uploadProgress.connect(self.handleUploadProgress)
            uploader.uploadFinished.connect(self.handleUploadFinished)
            uploader.upload(data, self.address)

    def handleUploadProgress(self, key, sent, total):
        print('upload(%d): %d [%d]' % (key, sent, total))
        progress = self.table.cellWidget(key, 1)
        progress.setValue(sent)

    def handleUploadFinished(self, key):
        print('upload(%d) finished' % key)
        button = self.table.cellWidget(key, 0)
        button.setDisabled(True)
        uploader = self._uploaders.pop(key)
        uploader.deleteLater()

    def handleAbort(self, key):
        try:
            self._uploaders[key].abort()
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass

class Uploader(QtCore.QObject):
    uploadProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, int)
    uploadFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, key, parent):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._key = key
        self._reply = None

    def abort(self):
        if self._reply is not None:
            self._reply.abort()

    def upload(self, data, url):
        if self._reply is None:
            self._stream = data
            self._multiPart = QtNetwork.QHttpMultiPart(QtNetwork.QHttpMultiPart.FormDataType)
            imagePart = QtNetwork.QHttpPart()
            fileName = QtCore.QFileInfo(self._stream.fileName()).fileName()
            key = 'image_field'
            imagePart.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentDispositionHeader,
                     "form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"" % (key, fileName))
            imagePart.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader,
                     'image/png')
            imagePart.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentLengthHeader,
                     self._stream.size())
            imagePart.setBodyDevice(self._stream);
            self._multiPart.append(imagePart)
            request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
            request.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader,
  'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % self._multiPart.boundary())
            self._reply = self.parent().post(request, self._multiPart)
            self._reply.uploadProgress.connect(self.handleUploadProgress)
            self._reply.error.connect(self.handleError)
            self._reply.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)

    def handleUploadProgress(self, sent, total):
        self.uploadProgress.emit(self._key, sent, total)
        if sent >= total:
            # prevent duplicated uploads
            self._reply.close()

    def handleFinished(self):
        #print(self._reply.readAll()) #uncomment it if you want see output
        self._multiPart.deleteLater()
        self._stream.deleteLater() #self._strem.close()
        self._reply.deleteLater()
        self._reply = None
        self.uploadFinished.emit(self._key)

    def handleError(self):
        print(self._reply.error())
        print(self._reply.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window('http://localhost/01/upload/123.php')
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and here is my HTML form :

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="123.php">
   <input type="file" size="32" name="image_field" value="">
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload">
 </form>
```

Comment: any reason for using QT to send requests?

Comment: Well,I'm new to PyQt/Python and the reason I'm using the Qt network classes is that it simplifies a lot of things,So it's best to start I guess

Comment: i usually recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)  its a really good/clean/documented api. Now sometimes its preference but i think you will find it much easier with requests

Comment: I need to upload large files and it need to be parallel,requests save file in memory,so it's not an option in here but thanks for your comment

Comment: @Mohammadhzp. Maybe you should first try to make a "toy" program in pure python that just tries to upload one file to the php script. Once you understand what the correct approach is, it should be fairly straightforward to translate it to work with PyQt. I think the Qt-specific aspects of your questions on this topic might put off a lot of python people on SO who would otherwise be willing to help you.

Comment: thanks ekhumoro for your answer,the reason I'm asking lots of questions is my limited time,I think in this case uploader is fine and there is no need for toy program(since I'm using pavell answer to upload file).even with pavell code I have problem with uploading since I don't know how to write and set headers,i.e there are two kind of header,setHeader and setRawHeader,plus,I can set header for both request and imagePart in my code,I'm sure uploader is fine and there is something wrong with headers,I couldn't find something complete about header so I was hoping here someone could help me

Comment: @Mohammadhzp. But have you searched for a pure python example that does what you need? There are a going to be a _lot_ more of those around than Qt ones. Don't waste time trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying but I thought headers are the same no matter what framework or package we are using.out of Qt it's only urllib3 which is Ok(if  read directly and not moving it to memory)

Comment: @Mohammadhzp. Yes, the headers are the same: that's _exactly_ why I made the suggestion I did!

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro,I'll try urllib3 which is another package in a simple situation to find the structure of http posting.Good luck

Comment: Ok,I tested both urllib3 and requests,urllib3 have some bug I guess...anyway I get requests working and toy program with request has the ability to upload,but 1- I didn't use any header,2- in docs says requests can handle streaming,but if it can handle,it will just for one upload,not parallel,in the meantime I was working on apache but I that didn't work out,do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: Ok,I suspect that maybe self._reply.close() is closing self.reply at first sign of progress,so I did remove it and now I have the ability to see PHP file,I echo a variable and I saw it from python,but still no luck in uploading file